# Sonarqube scan error with line out of range?

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

> [07:43:57]W:   [Step 1/1] ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
>
> [07:43:57]W:   [Step 1/1] ERROR: Line 523 is out of range in the file
> src/main/java/com/company/package/File.java
> (lines: 522)

For some reason Sonarqube is reporting an error on line 523 but there is only 522 lines in the source file ?

I saw this on a previous file, but when I added a blank line to the end of it the problem went away, this file already has a blank line at the end of it.

Comment: Which version of SonarQube and of Java Plugin are you using ? what is the encoding of _File.java_ on which this is failing ?

Comment: Hello, Having the same issue with SonarQube 5.6.2, java plugin 4.2, file encoded in utf-8

Comment: It seemed to just start working the day after I posted this.... No changes made

Comment: Having the same issue here. Using Maven on a groovy project with SonarQube 6.1.

Comment: I had the same issue and I resolved it by copy & pasting the entire contents of the offending class into TextWrangler, then copy & pasting it back into Visual Studio. It sounds silly, but I switch back & forth between developing on PC and Mac and I guess I normalized the line breaks at some point, which may have caused an issue.

Answer (score 29):

I had the same issue when using sonar maven plugin and jacoco test reports. `mvn sonar:sonar` relies on an existintig jacoco report, when the source code was changed (lines had been removed), but the test report wasn't updated this error occurred. Running `mvn clean test sonar:sonar` solved it.

Comment: True. I got the same problem and the cause was also an outdated jacoco report.

Answer (score 5):

I tried `gradle clean build`and it worked for me

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20135676)

Comment: @PankajMakwana Disagree. Just because it is short it does not mean it is not an answer. I see this as answer and not a comment.

Answer (score 4):

Same damn issue happens in python code as well. I got it resolved adding a blank line at the end of the file.

Comment: For me it was the coverage xml that wasn't refreshing with deleted files.

Answer (score 3):

For me it was because I had exactly the same class (for example `com.test.MyClass`) name and package name in two different sub modules (maven), `MyClass` in first module is larger i.e. 120 lines of code. `MyClass` in second module is shorter, then the exception was thrown since JaCoCo though the report was for that.

Solution was to rename one of the classes or move it into a different package.

i.e. :
`com.test.MyClass`
and
`com.test.MyClassB`

OR:

`com.test.MyClass`
and
`com.test.foo.MyClass`

Answer (score 2):

For Azure DevOps, you might want to make sure your build cleans sources before it starts building.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem on our AspNET-Core-Project.

We then saw, that we had testfailures that unfortunately didn't cause our Jenkins-Job to fail. Instead sonarqube analyzing the tests and coverage produced the error.

Once the tests were fixed everything worked well again.

Answer (score 0):

If executing a *maven clean* does not work check if you have any old project folder that needs to be cleaned. Once you remove a submodule from the maven pom it won't remove the folder including the /target directory with the jacoco report from ages ago.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, an iOS project written in Swift had to remove previous reports.
Just delete sonar-reports folder.

Answer (score 0):

I got the very same error with Azure DevOps Pipelines, but a cleanup before building the solution for `sources and output` did the job.

Now everything is working fine again.

Comment: How do you do this? I have this issue as part of an Azure DevOps pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Major reasons for this problem:-

1. Yes this issue arises when there is a recent change in the
   repository but you are not using the updated image in the yaml file and this error will always be seen in the latest committed file in the repo.

**for ex -
docker run -dt --name ${{variables.containerName}} ${{variables.tempimage}} /bin/bash**

2. In the above command we are invoking the containerName and then
   using some tempimage so if this tempimage is updated(means pointing
   to the latest repo) then only you will be able to resolve this issue
   if we have a mismatch in the repo at sonarqube and in the yaml file
   then we will get this issue.
3. To get the latest image we can use Team_image_builder inside the
   yaml file  and if we remove the latest committed file from the repo then this issue
   will not come because difference of both sides would be zero then.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the coverage reports from the previous run before running again.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid issues with the coverage report, make sure to delete it before executing it again. First, build your xml file and then execute sonar-scanner. To do this, run the following commands in sequence: coverage xml, coverage html, and sonar-scanner. Alternatively, you can try removing the .coverage and .scannerwork files.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, and after researching a lot, I found out that the Tests were not being built (so they are not reflecting the latest source code).

The first mistake: when calling msbuild.exe I was just using `msbuild.exe /t:Rebuild`, now I'm using `msbuild.exe /t:Clean;Rebuild` so I can see that no tests were being build anymore.

The second mistake: ignoreing the errors from TypeScript (or any other error). So by running msbuild.exe isolated, I was able to see that TypeScript error was breaking the msbuild execution before the tests can be build. Don't ignore any errors, and try to run the commands outside the script.

This way a fresh test DLL will be build, and when coverage will compare the methods/classes it will match the right source code file.