# SonarQube for MSBuild - End Analysis: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution Line out of range in the file

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

```
##[error]15:41:48.530 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
##[error]java.lang.IllegalStateException: Line 33 is out of range in the file Controllers/BaseAccessRequestController.cs (lines: 30)
```

I am using Sonar 5.6.5 version and MSBuild 14. Sonar is running as Windows Service. If I exclude this controller then same error comes for other random controller. If I exclude all controllers but keep one or two for which unit tests are written then error goes away but the coverage is shown as 0,0%.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I am able to fix this issue after removing Microsoft Build Tools 2015 and Visual studio Enterprise 2015 with Updates 2015 from TFS Build server and reinstalling it again.