# Running Sonarqube giving me the following error

Tags: c#, sonarqube, dotcover, sonarscanner

I am trying to build our c-sharp solution, and using dotcover for code coverage

the following are the output generated.

```
C:\Client\DEV\DEV_3.3.0\TEST> SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"Client-3.3.0" /n:"Client-3.3.0" /v:"2.0" /d:sonar.cs.dotcover.reportsPaths="C:\Client\DEV\DEV_3.3.0\TEST\CoverageReport.html"

SonarScanner for MSBuild 4.4.2
Using the .NET Framework version of the Scanner for MSBuild
Default properties file was found at C:\sonarqube\msbuild\SonarQube.Analysis.xml`
Loading analysis properties from C:\sonarqube\msbuild\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Pre-processing started.
Preparing working directories...
15:19:13.733  Updating build integration targets...
15:19:13.766  Fetching analysis configuration settings...
15:19:14.075  Provisioning analyzer assemblies for cs...
15:19:14.077  Installing required Roslyn analyzers...
15:19:14.203  Pre-processing succeeded.


C:\Client\DEV\DEV_3.3.0\TEST>
C:\Client\DEV\DEV_3.3.0\TEST>msbuild ..\source\Clientside.sln

.....
.....
.....
3013 Warning(s)
0 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:03:06.10
```

Now i am running the dotcover code analysis and test coverage

```
C:\Client\DEV\DEV_3.3.0\TEST>dotcover analyse /ReportType=HTML /Output="C:\Client\DEV\DEV_3.3.0\TEST\CoverageReport.html" /TargetExecutable="C:\Client\DEV\DEV_3.3.0\3rdparty\NUnit.Console-3.9.0\nunit3-console.exe" /TargetArguments="C:\Client\DEV\DEV_3.3.0\TEST\SAClientTest.nunit"
JetBrains dotCover Console Runner 2018.2.3. Build 777.0.20180912.160624
Copyright (c) 2009-2019 JetBrains s.r.o. All rights reserved.
[JetBrains dotCover] Coverage session started [1/11/2019 3:09:56 PM]
NUnit Console Runner 3.9.0
Copyright (c) 2018 Charlie Poole, Rob Prouse

Runtime Environment
   OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.16299.0
  CLR Version: 4.0.30319.42000

Test Files
    C:\Client\DEV\DEV_3.3.0\TEST\ClientTest.nunit


Errors, Failures and Warnings
......
......
......


 Test Run Summary
  Overall result: Failed
  Test Count: 83, Passed: 70, Failed: 13, Warnings: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Skipped: 0
    Failed Tests - Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Invalid: 0
  Start time: 2019-01-11 09:39:58Z
    End time: 2019-01-11 09:40:03Z
    Duration: 4.932 seconds

Results (nunit3) saved as TestResult.xml
[JetBrains dotCover] Coverage session finished [1/11/2019 3:10:05 PM]
[JetBrains dotCover] Analyzed application exited with code '13'
[JetBrains dotCover] Coverage results post-processing started [1/11/2019 3:10:05 PM]
[JetBrains dotCover] Report generation started [1/11/2019 3:10:05 PM]
[JetBrains dotCover] Report generation finished [1/11/2019 3:10:08 PM]
[JetBrains dotCover] Coverage results post-processing finished [1/11/2019 3:10:08 PM]
```

And this is the output after sonarscanner end operation.

```
C:\Client\DEV\DEV_3.3.0\TEST>SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end
SonarScanner for MSBuild 4.4.2
Using the .NET Framework version of the Scanner for MSBuild
Default properties file was found at C:\sonarqube\msbuild\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Loading analysis properties from C:\sonarqube\msbuild\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Post-processing started.
.....
SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS is not configured. Setting it to the default value of -Xmx1024m
Calling the SonarQube Scanner...
INFO: Scanner configuration file: C:\sonarqube\msbuild\sonar-scanner-3.2.0.1227\bin\..\conf\sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: C:\Client\DEV\DEV_3.3.0\TEST\.sonarqube\out\sonar-project.properties
............
INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java]
INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java] (done) | time=4ms
INFO: Sensor Analyzer for "php.ini" files [php]
INFO: Sensor Analyzer for "php.ini" files [php] (done) | time=3ms
INFO: No SCM system was detected. You can use the 'sonar.scm.provider' property to explicitly specify it.

........
......

INFO: Source encoding: windows-1252, default locale: en_US
INFO: Index files
INFO: 5 files indexed
INFO: Quality profile for cs: Sonar way
INFO: Sensor C# [csharp]
INFO: Importing analysis results from C:\Client\DEV\DEV_3.3.0\TEST\null\output-cs
INFO: Sensor C# [csharp] (done) | time=6ms
INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java]
INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java] (done) | time=0ms
INFO: Sensor Analyzer for "php.ini" files [php]
INFO: Sensor Analyzer for "php.ini" files [php] (done) | time=1ms
INFO: Sensor C# Tests Coverage Report Import [csharp]
INFO: Aggregating the HTML reports from C:\Client\DEV\DEV_3.3.0\TEST\CoverageReport.html
INFO: Parsing the dotCover report C:\Client\DEV\DEV_3.3.0\TEST\CoverageReport\src\1.html
INFO: Parsing the dotCover report C:\Client\DEV\DEV_3.3.0\TEST\CoverageReport\src\10.html
INFO: Parsing the dotCover report C:\Client\DEV\DEV_3.3.0\TEST\CoverageReport\src\100.html
INFO: Parsing the dotCover report C:\Client\DEV\DEV_3.3.0\TEST\CoverageReport\src\101.html
INFO: Parsing the dotCover report C:\Client\DEV\DEV_3.3.0\TEST\CoverageReport\src\102.html
INFO: Parsing the dotCover report C:\Client\DEV\DEV_3.3.0\TEST\CoverageReport\src\103.html
   ......

    .....

INFO: Adding this code coverage report to the cache for later reuse: C:\Client\DEV\DEV_3.3.0\TEST\CoverageReport.html
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
***INFO: Total time: 22.134s
INFO: Final Memory: 11M/44M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: Line 129 is out of range in the file source/PipeClient.cs (lines: 128)
ERROR:
The SonarQube Scanner did not complete successfully
15:10:44.674  Creating a summary markdown file...
15:10:44.685  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1

C:\Client\DEV\DEV_3.3.0\TEST>***
```

The last 10 lines are the errors

Sometimes it gives me different errors like this for the same code. I dont know to identify the cause.

```
INFO: Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 14.850s
INFO: Final Memory: 7M/85M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor
ERROR: Caused by: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.issue.ignore.scanner.IssueExclusionsLoader
ERROR: Caused by: Dangling meta character '*' near index 0
**/src/main/java/com/dell/customtools/integration/td/proxy/**
^
ERROR: 
The SonarQube Scanner did not complete successfully
21:11:25.365  Creating a summary markdown file...
21:11:25.369  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
WARN: Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succedeed?
ERROR: Execution of SonarScanner for MSBuild failed (exit code 1)
Archiving artifacts
Extended Email Publisher is currently disabled in project settings
Finished: FAILURE
```

FYI, i am using the following tools

1. Visual Studio professional 2017
2. dotcover Version: 2018.3.1
3. sonarqube - LTS - 6.7.x

P.S have tried these solutions too. 
[stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39753072/sonarqube-scan-error-with-line-out-of-range)
but none worked.

Comment: try to delete all analyse temp files under sonar scaner working directory between each analyse run and make sure there is no abbadonded scaner process  runing in background,

Comment: sonar scanner working directory ? can you please tell the location ?